# Is there any statistical evidence that 2 of 3 wallets are indeed the most common one?

Tags: multi-signature, wallet-security

I read the following statement:

> 2 of 3 wallets are the most common multi-signature wallets created. In
> this case, the wallet requires three signatures, but only two are
> needed to authorize a transaction.

Is there any statistical evidence that 2 of 3 wallets are indeed the most common one? Like some graph etc. Any kind of statistical evidence would be good. I want to use this fact in a research paper I am writing. I need some reference to cite.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, txstats.com has [such a graph](https://txstats.com/dashboard/db/p2sh-repartition-by-type?orgId=1). From this graph, we can see that 2-of-3 multisigs are by far the most popular multisig types.

[image]